# Airflow logs and kubernetes pod logs are different

Tags: airflow-scheduler, airflow

We are running airflow on kubernetes. Though airflow runs the DAGs without any issues but I see the below weird error messages in the airflow logs.

However, when I check the kubernetes pod logs where the DAG is running, it doesnt have any issues and all the tasks in the DAG completed successfully. Any reason why i'm getting the below error messages in the airflow logs? Also all the logs are not printed in the airflow logs though everything is printed without any error messages in kubernetes pod logs.

```
[2021-03-19 06:36:33,214] - Sending Signals.SIGTERM to GPID 86142
[2021-03-19 06:36:33,215] - Received SIGTERM. Terminating subprocesses.
[2021-03-19 06:36:33,450] - Pod Launching failed: Task received SIGTERM signal
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/airflow/contrib/operators/kubernetes_pod_operator.py", line 251, in execute
    get_logs=self.get_logs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/airflow/contrib/kubernetes/pod_launcher.py", line 117, in run_pod
    return self._monitor_pod(pod, get_logs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/airflow/contrib/kubernetes/pod_launcher.py", line 124, in _monitor_pod
    for line in logs:
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/urllib3/response.py", line 807, in __iter__
    for chunk in self.stream(decode_content=True):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/urllib3/response.py", line 571, in stream
    for line in self.read_chunked(amt, decode_content=decode_content):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/urllib3/response.py", line 763, in read_chunked
    self._update_chunk_length()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/urllib3/response.py", line 693, in _update_chunk_length
    line = self._fp.fp.readline()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/socket.py", line 589, in readinto
    return self._sock.recv_into(b)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/ssl.py", line 1071, in recv_into
    return self.read(nbytes, buffer)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/ssl.py", line 929, in read
    return self._sslobj.read(len, buffer)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/airflow/models/taskinstance.py", line 943, in signal_handler
    raise AirflowException("Task received SIGTERM signal")
airflow.exceptions.AirflowException: Task received SIGTERM signal

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/airflow/models/taskinstance.py", line 966, in _run_raw_task
    result = task_copy.execute(context=context)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/airflow/contrib/operators/kubernetes_pod_operator.py", line 263, in execute
    raise AirflowException('Pod Launching failed: {error}'.format(error=ex))
airflow.exceptions.AirflowException: Pod Launching failed: Task received SIGTERM signal
[2021-03-19 06:36:33,452] - Marking task as UP_FOR_RETRY
[2021-03-19 06:36:33,708] - Process psutil.Process(pid=86142, status='terminated', exitcode=1, started='04:24:15') (86142) terminated with exit code 1
[2021-03-19 06:36:37,599] -  2021-03-19 06:36:37,599 INFO - Task exited with return code 1
```

Thanks

Comment: Hi, Could anyone please let me know why am getting this issue where the airflow logs are not matching with Kubernetes pod logs. Thanks

Comment: My theory on the matter from experiencing this issue, is that log events from dags are captured and stored as a file or remotely so that airflow can show the logs via the UI. It would be nice if there was a way to also echo them so it gets picked up in the pod logs as well.